# How to change style property on one React component without changing them all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to change one style property of a specific React component when I click it without changing the style on every instance of that component.

I've read the React tutorial and looked through different answers and am not sure why every component changes when I just click on one of them (forgive me if that terminology is off). I've tried methods like e.target and some other things that worked in jQuery but I keep getting errors.

```
class Maze extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(); 
        this.state = {
            colorToChangeMaze: 'orange'
        }
    }
    idk=Array(9).fill(null)
    changeToRed=(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            colorToChangeMaze:'red'})
 }
    changeToBlack=(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            colorToChangeMaze:'black'})}

  render(){
      return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.changeToRed}>change To Red</button>
      <button onClick={this.changeToBlack}>change To Black</button>
      {this.idk.map(x=>  <Square onClick={this.changeToBlack} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}/>)} 
      </div>
  );}
}

class Square extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick = {this.props.onClick} style={{'height':'80px','width':'80px','backgroundColor':this.props.color,'margin':'0'}}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When I click on a square, I want just THAT square to change to black, not all of the squares, but all of the squares do. I kind of understand why my code doesn't work ('onClick' and 'backgroundColor' point to the same state), but I can't think of anything that would. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are guessing the right thing about your problem. So, you can track the index of elements or create a unique id for your elements and keep a "clicked" state.

Comment: not sure if it a typo or not but 'margin':'0'}}> seems with an extra 
"}" , please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the `<Square />` components are changing color because they all share the same state.

If you want each Square to change color independently, then each `<Square />` component will need to manage its own state.

Let's explore how we might solve this:

First, expand your Square component by giving it its own state. Then, let's detect if the `isBlack` state property is true. If so, we set the background color to black. If false, we use whatever color we pass into the Square component's `color` prop.

```
class Square extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isBlack: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { handleClick, color } = this.props;
    const { isBlack } = this.state;
    return (
      <div onClick={handleClick} style={{height:'80px', width:'80px', backgroundColor: isBlack ? 'black' : color, margin:0 }} />
    )
  }
}
```